# Only allow children of certain type in WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

In one of my applications I need to allow the user to customize the user interface in certain ways. To do so, I'm allowing the user to specify the user interface in XAML, which I load dynamically when the application is started. This works fine.

Now I want to provide custom control to the user, which is derived from `Border` (let's call it `MyFrame`).

I need to make sure that `MyFrame` may not be child of another `MyFrame`, so the following should be prevented:

```
<ns:MyFrame>
    <Grid>
        <ns:MyFrame />
    </Grid>
</ns:MyFrame>
```

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this at compile time.

However, at runtime, you can check whenever a new instance of MyFrame is created, if it has a parent MyFrame, using [this visual tree walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls). If it does, raise an exception.

Comment: it's not *always* work (in my exp. +-70% of cases), but it's absolutely valid option to try.

Comment: What do you mean when saying it doesn't *always* work? Of course, I want a solution that works in 100% of the cases. Otherwise I might save time and not implement it...

Comment: Actually, Tigran probably had trouble using the methods provided in the link i gave, because you have to be careful with XAML instantiation order: if you try to find something that gets instantiated after you check, you might find nothing whereas there should be something. Keep this in mind, and it's a 100% solution =)

Comment: I've used the `TryFindParent` method from the link you provided and am calling it in `MyFrame`'s `OnVisualParentChanged` method. Thus, I'm checking for the existence of a parent when the child is (re)assigned to a parent. In that case I suppose that both are created and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an exception with a clear message from the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event handler on MyFrame: step through the ancestors of the new MyFrame instance and try to find another one; if you do find one, throw the exception.

Alternative: use an inheritable attached property that you set on all instances of MyFrame - and check that in the Loaded handler.

I can't imagine any way to enforce your rule in a static manner.

Comment: While I'm doing what you suggested, I found the code in Baboon's link. That's why I'm accepting his answer.

Comment: Sure :) I had to re-register cos I forgot my old user/pass, so he beat me to it hehe